# Locking database record for editing

Tags: asp.net, sql, locking

I have a SQL Server 2008 database and an asp.net frontend.

I would like to implement a lock when a user is currently editing a record but unsure of which is the best approach.

My idea is to have an `isLocked` column for the records and it gets set to true when a user pulls that record, meaning all other users have read only access until the first user finishes the editing.

However, what if the session times out and he/she never saves/updates the record, the record will remain with `isLocked = true`, meaning others cannot edit it, right?

How can I implement some sort of session time out and have `isLocked` be automatically set to false when the session times out (or after a predefined period)

Should this be implemented on the asp.net side or the SQL side?

Comment: Are you really really sure you want to do this as opposed to using optimistic locking. There are a a few ways to force a lock in sql server, but they start messy and get worse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't do it at all. Use [optimistic concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa0416cz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Pessimistic locking is possible, but not from .Net applications. .Net app farms are not technically capable of maintaining a long lived session to keep a lock (obtained via [`sp_getapplock`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx) or, worse, obtained by real data locking) because .Net app farms:

- load balance requests across instances
- do not keep a request stack between HTTP calls
- recycle the app domain

Before you say 'I don't have a farm, is only one IIS server' I will point out that you may only have one IIS server **now** and if you rely on it you will never be able to scale out, and you *still* have the problem of app-domain recycle.

Simulating locking via app specific updates (eg. 'is_locked' field) is deeply flawed in real use, for reasons you already started to see, and many more. When push comes to shove this is the only approach that *can* be made to work, but I never heard of *anyone* saying 'Gee, I'm really happy we implemented pessimistic locking with data writes!'. Nobody, ever.

App layer locking is also not workable, for exactly the same reasons .Net farms cannot use back-end locking (load-balancing, lack of context between calls, app-domain recycle). Writing a distributed locking app-protocol is just not going to work, that road is paved with bodies.

Just don't do it. Optimistic concurrency is sooooo much better in every regard.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. As far as scalability goes, for this particular application at least, it will never go over 50 users and because the data is not vast I could even get away with using dataset optimistic concurrency but I believe timestamping works a bit better. The thing is, let's say a user pulls a record and enters a lot data/text in a couple of fields. Then at the same time another user goes in and does a quick,small update. The first user's data does not get saved (and gets lost) but the second user should never have been able to make a change. How to implement just that?

Comment: There is 0 (zero) reasons  for the updates to get lost. The app is more than welcomed to apply any business logic to merge the changes and, in case of conflict, display to the user a new form asking to reconcile the conflict.

Comment: Makes sense. If I would like to perform timestamping checks via a stored procedure that alters 1 row on multiple tables, how would the timestamping be checked then?

Comment: This is business logic. Will depend based on your business requirements.